# How do I configure JBoss to only accept local connections on HTTP?

Tags: jboss

I configured JBoss to use AJP over Apache for all outgoing connections, but I want to set up the internal 8080 for local connections. How can I do this within the context of JBoss so I don't need to block a port on the firewall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [Remote Access Filter](http://www.jboss.org/file-access/default/members/jbossweb/freezone/docs/latest/config/valve.html#Remote%20Address%20Filter).
An example for the syntax is given on [this page](http://www.jboss.org/file-access/default/members/jbossweb/freezone/docs/latest/config/engine.html) (at the end of the page).